# Why can I call destructor on a fundamental type in a template?

Tags: c++

I was implementing some templates for a memory allocator and came across some code that's compiling that I expected to not compile.  After writing and testing a template function to call a destructor, I found that it still worked after passing in an `int*`.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Class>
void CallDestructor(Class* InObj)
{
    InObj->~Class();
}

int main()
{
    int* test = new int;
    *test = 5;
    std::cout << *test << std::endl;
    CallDestructor(test); // Why does this compile?
    //test->~int();       // This does not compile which is what I expected for template function
    std::cout << *test << std::endl;
    delete test;
}
```

The code compiles and runs on www.cpp.sh and also in Visual Studio 2013 for me.

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: So you don't have to handle special cases... isn't it handy?

Comment: It's very handy, but I was fully ready to try out `std::is_fundamental`.

Comment: Thanks, the duplicate answer explained it very well.